# How do i connect my Galaxy S3 to my computer?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, connection-issues, usb-connection-mode

I Have tried everything i can find to connect my galaxy S3 to my computer, I have used different cables, and Different ports on my computer. My phone will connect to other computers just fine, but on mine it says "Can not recognise USB device. please reconnect and try again." Is this a computer issue, or just my phone?

Comment: What OS and version?

Comment: [Have you checked Samsung's website for up-to-date drivers?](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads "Have you checked for drivers from Samsung?")

Comment: A simple PC restart?

Comment: i'm on Android 4.4.2 Kit Kat

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, this happens when there is another program or driver that is monitoring the USB ports for the operating system. I have had problems with my Logitech gaming device drivers causing this sort of problem.

Answer (score 1):

Samsung has a webpage [here](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000117) for drivers for development purposes (ADB things) but I believe they will work for transferring files as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem some time ago with my S3. The phone would connect and try to install drivers, but at the end the phone still wouldn't show up no matter how I tried to connect it.

If I recall correctly, I had to use the drivers that were shown on this [XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=961956). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your PC has a fault in its USB port.

This might have been caused by some device driver errors. It could be hardware failure too.

Comment: How are you sure it is a faulty USB Port? Mind elaborating?

Comment: OP wrote: "*I have used different cables, and Different ports on my computer. My phone will connect to other computers just fine*". Please avoid making guesses in answers. Use comments for that.

Comment: This is not a guess. I have experienced similar problem. And I am pretty sure the OP is using some Custom ROM which can cause issues with the device drivers of the PC.

Comment: Updating the device drivers of the PC might correct the problem. Also, using a ROM which has high support and is fairly trusted would be better.

Comment: It can't be a fault in the USB port because it worked fine about a month ago and my PC can still charge my phone. (should have put that in the original question, sorry)

Comment: Yes, this could be issue with the firmware on your device then. And I would still recommend updating your drivers. And kindly post the screenshot of device manager(Universal Serial Bus Controllers) in PC.

Comment: What ROM do you have on your device?